# Erro PHP Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in

Tags: php

começou a aparecer o erro

**PHP Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for strings in**

```
$data = date('Y-m-d');

$q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM agendasalao WHERE dataReserva >= $data ORDER BY dataReserva ASC");


$qtde_registros = mysqli_num_rows($q);
if ($qtde_registros > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
        $data[] = $row;  <<< erro aqui
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: puts... essa variavel ta errada mesmo. erro bobo. vou mudar para $dataAtual .

Comment: Só um detalhe, construir queries usando o coringa *,  é uma péssima ideia para a performance do código. Tente resgatar apenas os atributos necessários ao funcionamento da rotina definindo em sua clausula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está sendo indicado corretamente.

Você cria uma string no começo do código:

```
$data = ...
```

Ou seja, uma cadeia de caracteres. No loop você quer adicionar ítens:

```
$data[] = ...
```

Itens são adicionados em *arrays*, e não em strings.

### Solução imediata:

Se realmente é para acumular tudo na mesma variável...

... ou troca o começo para isto...:

```
$data[] = date('Y-m-d');
```

... Ou adapta no loop:

```
$data .= $row-> (aqui você poe o item desejado do objeto retornado);
```

Se não é esta a intenção, basta mudar o nome de uma das duas variáveis.